# Is it safe to run a laptop with possible BGA damage if you don't plan on using the video alot?

Tags: laptop, security, physical-damage

I have a junker laptop that I want to run Linux on and just SSH into.  I believe that the [BGA of the videocard](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/2047/diy-bga-soldering-feasability) has some damage, do I really need to reflow this sucker before using it, or is it safe to install Linux on it, ssh in, and just keep the lid down so the monitor stays off?

By "Safe" I mean It's not going catch on fire

Comment: Define "Safe"..

Comment: @Moab It's not going catch on fire...

Comment: Just because the monitor is off does not mean the video chip is not being used, to be on the safe side, I would say No.

Comment: Darn...a reflow sounds tricky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say no, it is not safe, its not worth the risk of fire to find out.

You can [have it professionally repaired.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZFWwk27t7ww)

Most of the time gpu's that fail connections are due to poor heat dissipation engineering issues and the problem will re occur eventually even if repaired properly. In other words a poorly designed laptop cooling system or GPU heat sink, or both.